# Procedural Paper Tearing Effect in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I am looking for suggestions on how to set up a procedural paper tearing effect with GN.

Can anyone think of a way to achieve a look similar to this reference, but done entirely procedurally?

[image: Paper Tear]

I'm thinking: Generate a primitive plane, Throw some points all over the edges, then randomly select and transform those points along the Z-axis... but I'm still learning the nodes and I'm not sure how to set that up.

Additionally, I would like to be able to animate the top layer peeling back (using a modifier) to reveal another layer underneath.  Like this:

[image: tear 2]